# tcpip connection refused when used as service in raspbian

Tags: java, jar, raspbian

I have a `jar` file that listen to tcpip requests and send data accordingly.
this `jar` file needs to run on a service in raspbian.

i've followed the instructions on [this link](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/ubuntu-16-java-service-wrapper-example)

I've create sh file and put it in `/usr/local/bin` (`Tourmaline.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=Tourmaline
PATH_TO_JAR=/usr/local/bin/Tourmaline.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/Tourmaline-pid
case $1 in
start)
    echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
    if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
        exec java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                    echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
    else
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
    fi
;;
stop)
    if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
        PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
        kill $PID;
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
        rm $PID_PATH_NAME
    else
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
    fi
;;
restart)
    if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
        PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
        kill $PID;
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
        rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
        nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                    echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
    else
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
    fi
;;
esac
```

when i run `"sudo Tourmaline.sh start"` on the terminal, the program starts to work and when i send a request i'm getting a response.

this was phase 1.
next, i've created a service script and put it in `/etc/systems/system` (`Tourmaline.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description = Tourmaline
After= network.target

[Service]
Type = forking
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/Tourmaline.sh start
ExecStop = /usr/local/bin/Tourmaline.sh stop
ExecReload = /usr/local/bin/Tourmaline.sh reload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've enable the service using `"sudo systemctl enable Tourmaline"`
and start it with `"sudo systemctl start Tourmaline.service"`

in the status i can see that the service started and active
However, when i send a request i'n getting `"connection refused"` **error**
i try to run `"sudo Tourmaline.sh start"` but it says

> the program is already running (because the service started).

how can i make the service accepts connections?

Comment: Which port is the program trying to open? For privileged ports < 1024 the service needs to run as root. You could also check with 'netstat -l' whether your program is listening on the port that it is supposed to use.

Comment: it listen to port 2101, i check with netstat -l for used ports but my program not in there (even when the program works)

Comment: It just shows the ports and not the program. If the program works the output should contain something like `tcp        0      0 *:2101                  *:*                     LISTEN`

Comment: when i'm start the program via Tourmaline.service i'm not getting any tcp listen, however when i'm start the program via Tourmaline.sh i'm getting tcp6  (local address) [::]:rtcm-sc104 (foreign address) [::]:* (state) LISTEN